# Apache authentification error

Tags: php, linux, apache2.2, debian-based

I've installed Apache 2.2 on my Debian-based distr (kernel 3.2.0-27) and apache2.2-common package with default configs.

Trying to run simple script info.php I got the error found in /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Wed Jul 16 09:17:08 2014] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /info.php
```

I've searched for hours in the internet, but haven't found solution.

Script info.php:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Config files:

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
...
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
...
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf is clear.

/etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
...
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
...
```

/etc/apache2/conf.d/security:

```
...
ServerSignature On
TraceEnable Off
...
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/@000-default
(link to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

List of loaded modules (got by `apache2ctl -M`):

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 authn_default_module (static)
 authz_default_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

What changes should I make to make server work?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you might not have the php mod loaded. uncomment or add the line "LoadModule php5_module path/to/the/file/libphp5.so" in httpd.conf, obv putting in the actual filepath

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys, I've found out that I work not with original Apache but with its custom build in which work without authorization is disabled. Thanks for your comments.